# Firefox not executing scripts loaded dynamically via another external script

Tags: javascript, firefox

I've been having trouble with Firefox not executing JavaScript files that were loaded dynamically via an external script.

Let me explain.

I have the following HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Restive.JS</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/load.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Loading JavaScript</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside my *load.js* file, I have the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    function loadScript(url) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    var list_arr = ['assets/js/test1.js', 'assets/js/test2.js'];
    for (var i = 0; i < list_arr.length; i++) {
        loadScript(list_arr[i]);
    }
});
```

And inside *test1.js* and *test2.js*, I have `console.log('test1.js is loaded!');` and `console.log('test2.js is loaded!');`.

The problem is that *test1.js* and *test2.js* are loaded (I can see both files in the `<head>` via inspection), but they are never executed (because no messages appear in the console log).

However, when I change the format of script reference in my original HTML by inlining the JavaScript i.e. changing from this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/load.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    function loadScript(url) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    var list_arr = ['assets/js/test3.js', 'assets/js/test4.js'];
    for (var i = 0; i < list_arr.length; i++) {
        console.log('i = ' + i);
        loadScript(list_arr[i]);
    }
});
</script>
```

Then the scripts are loaded and executed.

I don't see this behaviour in Chrome or Safari, only Firefox. Also, inlining is not an option because this functionality is built-in to a library that users will have to reference via an external link.

Is this a problem that is fixable?

**EDIT**

I'm on a Mac OSX 10.10.5 using Firefox 46.0.1

Comment: This appears to be working for me in Win7 FF46.

Comment: Ok. I just tried it on BrowserStack with Win 8 and Firefox 46 and I'm having the same issue.